# Multicolumn ListBox Population on Startup - Run-time error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to populate three different columns of a list box with user information specified on a unique sheet

I was able to do so with one column, but I am having trouble when I try to add several columns. I would like to select the data necessary and give each column its on respective array, but it keeps telling me that my subscript is out of range.

If I assign one range to one array I can populate the list box using the line:

`Sheet1.name_List.List() = FirstNameArray`

Otherwise I have tried using the following code to populate all three of the columns...

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    i = 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating() = False

    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

    N = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    FirstNameArray = Range("A2:A" & N)
    SecondNameArray = Range("B2:B" & N)
    nIDArray = Range("C2:C" & N)

    For i = 0 To N
        With Sheet1.name_List
            .AddItem
            .List(i, 0) = FirstNameArray(i)
            .List(i, 1) = SecondNameArray(i)
            .List(i, 2) = nIDArray(i)
        End With
    Next i

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

*******EDIT******

After reviewing the comments I revised my code to the following block:

```
For i = LBound(FirstNameArray) To UBound(FirstNameArray)
    With Sheet1.name_List
        .AddItem
        .List(i, 0) = FirstNameArray(i, 1)
        .List(i, 1) = SecondNameArray(i, 1)
        .List(i, 2) = nIDArray(i, 1)
    End With
Next i
```

It looks like the FirstNameArray is assigning its first index to the first column of the listbox, but I get an error when it tries to assign the SecondNameArray. It says invalid property value..

Comment: @Domenic explained it in his post already: `.List(i, 0)` should be `.List(i-1, 0)`, lists use a 0-based index.

Answer (score 1):

When assigning a range from the worksheet to a Variant array, whether the range is one column or multiple columns, you're assigning a 2 dimensional array. So, to refer to the first item in your array, you'll need to include the second dimension.  Also, note that the index for the List property is 0-based, while the array is 1-based.  Therefore, your For/Next loop should be as follows...

```
With Sheet1.name_list
    For i = LBound(FirstNameArray) To UBound(FirstNameArray)
        .AddItem
        .List(i - 1, 0) = FirstNameArray(i, 1)
        .List(i - 1, 1) = SecondNameArray(i, 1)
        .List(i - 1, 2) = nIDArray(i, 1)
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I know I'm so close! The FirstNameArray element is assigned to  the first row of the first column, but the SecondNameArray isn't.

Comment: It looks like each array is assigned correctly, but there is a problem with the ListBox. I'm getting an 'Invalid Property Value' error when I run.

Comment: In design mode properties I made sure the ListBox has 3 columns.. In the debugger it seems to be the .List lines after the FirstNameArray assignment.

Comment: you can do .columnCount = 3, but what I assume you did wrong as I already pointed out in your OP `.List(i, 0)` should be `.List(i - 1, 0)`.

Comment: With the AddItem method, you can only assign values for the first 10 columns.  Are you trying to assign them to more columns?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you "leave" the array.

You have N - 1 Values in your Array:
`Range("A2:A" & N)` with N = 5 will give you an array with 4 entries (A2,A3,A4,A5).

But `For i = 0 To N` will loop 6 Times, (0,1,2,3,4,5)

Use `UBound` and `LBound` to loop arrays:

`For i = LBound(FirstNameArray) To UBound(FirstNameArray)`

Also, your `Range` objects are not fully qualified and will implicitly refer to activesheet. More on this here: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/03/15/vba-trap-default-members/

So for example do this at the beginning:
Edit: now uses 2d-arrays as @Domenic suggested in the comment of OT

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    dim i as long
    dim lastRow as long
    dim sht1 as excel.worksheet
    dim sht2 as excel.worksheet
    dim completeArray as Variant


    set sht1 = thisWorkbook.Worksheeets("Sheet1")
    set sht2 = thisWorkbook.Worksheeets("Sheet2")

    Application.ScreenUpdating() = False

    lastRow  = sht2.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    completeArray = sht2.Range("A2:C" & lastRow)

    With sht1.name_List
        .ColumnCount = 3
        'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function
        For i = LBound(completeArray, 1) To UBound(completeArray, 1)
            .AddItem
            .List(i - 1, 0) = completeArray(i, 1)
            .List(i - 1, 1) = completeArray(i, 2)
            .List(i - 1, 2) = completeArray(i, 3)
        Next i
    End With

    sht1.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I tired this and I am still getting a "Subscript Out of Range" error inside the For loop.

Comment: Edited so it incorporates @Domenics `i-1` for the list index. all the credit goes to him.